# Using select activity to remove column from source dataset that has dynamic filepath

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In in my dataflow, I have a source that references a dataset whos file path references a pipeline variable

I also have a select activity that I use to select the columns I want to map to my sink data set. In my select activity I have mappings under the input column. These mappings are causing the error: "Input column in mapping cannot be found for my select activity." I think this happens because my source in the dataflow shows up as 0 columns

[select activity input columns mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1qdI.png)

[source dataset showing 0 total columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZh3e.png)

How do I fix this?
Or is there another activity I can use to remove a column in my dataflow?

I have around 40 columns and want to select all except for 1 column

Comment: Did you tried to import the projection in the source of the dataflow? and the column in the select, are those manually created by you?

Comment: Hello, @RakeshGovindula the columns were imported from when I used an actual file instead of the variable filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using dataset parameter for the filename, the schema is not imported in dataflow which is why it is showing `0` columns.

You need to import the projection in the dataflow source. But the projection needs the value for the file name parameter. For the dataflow debug and for further transformations, we need some sample data. So, provide your sample file name as static value for the file name parameter in the projection.

At the time of pipeline debug, the file name parameter will be taken from the pipeline dataflow activity.

[image]

Click on save and now you can see the schema. The dataflow data preview and further transformations works on this data.

[image]

You can change data type if you want.

Coming to removing a specific column, you can use Rule based mapping in the select transformation.

[image]

Remove all columns and add a **Rule based mapping**. In this give your condition for the column name. Here I have given a sample condition `name!='Id'` to remove `Id` column. Give `$$` in the next expression.

You can see the column `Id` was removed here.

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you Rakesh